# Ajuda com CSS para Iphone em site

Tags: css, iphone

Estou postando para um colega meu. O site dele: www.consultapelaplaca.com.br tem uma imagem BG de carros passando.

Essa imagem não aparece no Iphone/Safari, ficando um fundo totalmente cinza.

O engraçado é que basicamente o mesmo CSS é usado na www.consultapelaplaca.com.br/comprar e nela o BG aparece.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Desculpe não estar falando sobre a pergunta mas que plugin você usou naquela contagem de números.

Comment: Cara, parece que é alguma coisa com o plugin de slider... 
Não tenho iPhone e nem Safari para testar aqui, mas só pode ser isso.

Comment: @Bruno este tema é pronto não sei qual é.

Comment: @PeterParker mas deveria dar pau na /comprar, pq é identico!